# How FutureTask is asynchronous computation

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, futuretask

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                 .............
                 .............
                 .............
    }
}).start();
```

If i will do this in main it will create a new thread and will submit a task to it for asynchronous calculation.

If you see FutureTask [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) it also says:

> A cancellable asynchronous computation. This class provides a base
>   implementation of Future, with methods to start and cancel a
>   computation, query to see if the computation is complete, and retrieve
>   the result of the computation.

So how `FutureTask` is an **`asynchronous computation`** does it create thread internally and submit the task that we give it at the time of instantiating `FutureTask` like:

```
FutureTask f = new FutureTask(new MyCallable());
```

Otherwise it can't be an asynchronous computation , please provide me the code snippet  from the `FutureTask` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java)  where it submits the task to thread, to make it asynchronous computation. Thanks.

---

**I got the answer.** It's is basically trying to run the task in the same thread as that of caller. It is pretty evident in the given code:

When you call `futureTask.run()` it just calls `sync.innerRun();` and `sync` is the instance of inner class `Sync`. In that it just calls `call()` on the callable object in the same thread.

```
void innerRun() {
        if (!compareAndSetState(READY, RUNNING))
            return;

        runner = Thread.currentThread(); //here it is getting the current thread
        if (getState() == RUNNING) { 
            V result;
            try {
                result = callable.call();//here calling call which executes in the caller thread.
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                setException(ex);
                return;
            }
            set(result);
        } else {
            releaseShared(0); // cancel
        }
    }
```

Comment: `FutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V>`, it is itself a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how FutureTask is an asynchronous computation does it create thread internally and submit the task that we give it at the time of instantiating FutureTask like:

`FutureTask` is not designed to be used directly by the user. It is designed to be used through the `ExecutorService` interface and the classes that implement it.  It is those classes that use `FutureTask` and fork the threads, etc..  You may need to read more information about [how to use the `ExecutorService` concurrency classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class is the main one that actually does the management of the threads in the pool.  Typically you call `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` to get an instance of it.

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// define your jobs somehow
for (MyCallable job : jobsToDo) {
    // under the covers this creates a FutureTask instance
    Future future = threadPool.submit(job);
    // save the future if necessary in a collection or something
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
// now we can go back and call `future.get()` to get the results from our jobs
```

From an academic standpoint, under the covers TPE extends `AbstractExecutorService` and it is there that you can see the `FutureTask` class being used to manage the tasks in the thread-pool:

```
public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<T> ftask = newTaskFor(task);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
...
protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
}
```

The code inside of TPE is pretty complicated and it's not easy to show a "snippet" that performs the asynchronous calls.  The TPE sees if it needs to add more threads to the pool. submits it to a task queue which can either reject it or accept it, and then the threads dequeue the task and run them in the background.

Comment: sometime we do also `futureTask.run()` is it not asynchronous task computation or it is just running on the same thread which is eventually caller?

Comment: `FutureTask.run()` is just calling the `run()` method of your task with some locking.  It does not fork any threads @Trying.  You should not call that directly.

Comment: Right @Trying.  It just calls it directly in the same thread.  Take a look at the source for `FutureTask`.

Comment: You should read up on the `ExecutorService` classes @Trying: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html