# compareAndSwap a common member ( non-volatile member ) still has memory semantics of volatile read and write

Tags: java, volatile, unsafe, compare-and-swap

When i read `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` in jdk1.8, i see the comment that `compareAndSetState` method  has memory semantics of a volatile read and write .

The comment and code are as follows:

```
/**
 * Atomically sets synchronization state to the given updated
 * value if the current state value equals the expected value.
 * This operation has memory semantics of a {@code volatile} read
 * and write.
 */
protected final boolean compareAndSetState(int expect, int update) {
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, expect, update);
}
```

In AbstractQueuedSynchronizer class, the `stateOffset` is a volatile member called `state`

Just wonder what memory semantics is if `state` is  a non-volatile member ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics for `compareAndSetState()` are still that of a volatile read and write - this is the main reason why `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt()` exists.

But usually the code doesn't only call `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt()`. Usually the code reads the current value, calculates a new value and then tries to replace the value it has read with the new value. And this read **also** must be done using volatile read semantics.

For example, in [`CountDownLatch.Sync#tryReleaseShared()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.java#L176):

> ```
>    protected boolean tryReleaseShared(int releases) {
>        // Decrement count; signal when transition to zero
>        for (;;) {
>            int c = getState();
>            if (c == 0)
>                return false;
>            int nextc = c-1;
>            if (compareAndSetState(c, nextc))
>                return nextc == 0;
>        }
>    }
> ```

Reading the `state` with `getState()` must use volatile read semantics to make sure it uses the latest value.

And yes, in principle you could refuse to declare a field like `state` as volatile. But then you **must** make sure that every access to that field goes through `compareAndSwapInt()`, `getIntVolatile()` and `putIntVolatile()`. If some maintainer of the code forgets this rules and adds a single direct read of the field your code will break in unexpected ways at the most disadvantageous moment in time - for example while giving a presentation to an important customer.

Comment: What i want to understand is `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt()` has the semantics of volatile read and write，not because of a volatile member compareAndSwapInt... but if `getState()` use `unsafe.getIntVolatile()`, and `setState()` use `unsafe.putIntVolatile()`, can i theoretically remove the keyword volatile on state  member?

Comment: @liuchiself I've expanded my answer - with an explanation why IMHO this is a bad idea.